# Get an object from php file to JS file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've had a browse through similar questions but I can't seem to get the solutions to work. I am trying to send a object from a php file to a js file using ajax. I can `print_r($decoded)` in the php file and then output this as a string from the js file. However I cannot seem to parse/convert this back to an object for use in the js file. I would like to do this as I want to access multiple properties from the object later on. I *think* it needs to be done through ajax as a variable that I need to pass to the php script is dynamically generated before being sent based on keyup/keydown input. Some answers suggest something like

```
$.getJSON("decide-token.php", function(data) {
  alert("Value for 'a': " + data.a + "\nValue for 'b': " + data.b);
});
```

but I don't think this would work for me.

This is my most recent attempt from some older answers on similar questions:

**main.js**

```
tokenKey.bind('keyup keydown', function(){
    var the_key = tokenKey.val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '../http/decode-token.php',
      type: 'post',
      dataType : 'json',
      data: {
        'token': token,
        'key' : the_key
      },
      success: function(data, status) {
        var obj = $.getJSON(data);
          console.log(obj.iat);
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr),
        console.log('Details: '  + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    }); // end AJAX
```

**decode-token.php**

```
require '../includes/bootstrap.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$token = $_POST['token'];
$key = $_POST['key'];

$decoded=JWT::decode($token, $key, array('HS256'));

echo json_encode($decoded);
```

I am currently printing this error to the console:

```
Details: parsererror
Error:SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are getting this message in the console based on the `success` portion of the ajax return, do `console.log(data);` right before the `var obj = $.getJSON(data);` and that will likely show you are getting an error in the PHP side that is malforming your json. It might say `<b>Warning....etc....{"whatever":"something"}` so that warning messes up your `echo json_encode($decoded);`.

Comment: @Rasclatt seems I get a 403 warning and "You don't have permission to access the requested object" - any idea on a fix?

Comment: I might think about putting an absolute-based path in the ajax, just to make sure it's actually going to the right place based on the root domain: `url: 'http://www.example.com/http/decode-token.php',` (whatever the actual path is) and see if it comes back as forbidden. It's possible the path is not right. I would also make sure you don't have some `.htaccess` or similar blocking request(s) to that directory.

Comment: @Rasclatt I don't think that would be the issue as I can retrieve the string representation of the object. Its a localhost which I set up so no .htaccess etc blocking

Comment: Perhaps in ``decode-token.php`` add ``header('Content-Type: application/json');`` before ``echo json_encode``, alternatively in your ``main.js`` try modifying your ``success`` function like ``var obj = $.getJSON(JSON.parse(data));``.